# Protobuf | How to map enum values?

Tags: protocol-buffers

In Protobuf, I have defined an enum:

```
enum OrderStatus {
    UNSPECIFIED_ORDER_STATUS = 0;
    ORDER_STATUS_NEW = 1;
    ORDER_STATUS_FILLED = 2;
}
```

The actual value we get from the server does not have the prefix:

```
{
"orderStatus": "new"
}
```

I need the prefix, otherwise a conflict is introduced (another enum has value "NEW")

Now, if I generate protobuf files (for Go), I get OrderStatus_value mapping as below:

```
OrderStatus_value = map[string]int32{
        "UNSPECIFIED_ORDER_STATUS":          0,
        "ORDER_STATUS_NEW":                  1,
        "ORDER_STATUS_FILLED":               2,
    }
```

**Question:** Is there any way I can manually map an enum in protobuf to the corresponding value?

F.ex:

```
num OrderStatus {
        UNSPECIFIED_ORDER_STATUS = 0;
        ORDER_STATUS_NEW = 1 [json_value = "new"];
        ORDER_STATUS_FILLED = 2 [json_value = "filled"];
    }
```

Expected result would be something like:

```
OrderStatus_value = map[string]int32{
            "UNSPECIFIED_ORDER_STATUS":          0,
            "new":                  1,
            "filled":               2,
        }
```

Comment: The JSON (!?) you receive from the server includes a field `orderStatus` of type string (not an enum). Does the server implement a protobuf schema? If so, why don't you use that instead? If you have a server that sends a string but you've some other service in which you want to convert the string to an enum, you should implement this mapping in your code (rather than adjust the protobuf stub).